# nvd3 pie outerRadius

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart, nvd3.js

I can not figure out how to change the radius in the diagram

```
nv.addGraph( function() {

    var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
            .x(function(d) { return d.label })
            .y(function(d) { return d.value })
            .width( 520)
            .height( 250)
            .donut( true)
            .showLabels( false)


    d3.select( '#stat-lang svg')
            .datum( data)
            .transition().duration(1200)
            .call( chart)

    return chart;
});
```

I use NVD3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the source code...

```
var availableWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right,
    availableHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    radius = Math.min(availableWidth, availableHeight) / 2,
    arcRadius = radius-(radius / 5), // radius
    container = d3.select(this);
```

...the radius is calculated based on width and height, taking the smallest of the two. So,  you can only adjust the radius by feeding these dimensions to the chart, like:

```
var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
    .x(function(d) { return d.label })
    .y(function(d) { return d.value })
    .showLabels(true)
    .donut(true)
    .donutRatio(0.35)
    .width(500) // width
    .height(500); // height
```

Answer (score 1):

use chart.arcRadius : {"inner":0.6,"outer":0.9} is used to adjust inner and outer radius
chart.donutRatio(0.5) is percent of pie radius to cut out of the middle to make the donut. It is multiplied by the outer radius to calculate the inner radius, thus it should be between 0 and 1.Default is 0.5

Answer (score 0):

To change the radius, use:

```
chart.arcsRadius({"inner":0.6,"outer":0.8})
```

For more information check [the examples](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#pieChart).